# PHP doesn't create table from query

Tags: php, html, mysql

This query doesn't work.
Any idea? Thank you

```
 $nuovidati = "CREATE TABLE '$user'
(
descrizione varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
data date NOT NULL,
entrata varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
uscita varchar(10000) DEFAULT NULL,
saldo varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
)";
 mysql_query($nuovidati) OR die("Errore 003, contattare l'amministratore ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: does the die message give you a mysql error message?

Comment: No but table doesn't create

Answer (score 6):

```
 $nuovidati = "CREATE TABLE '$user'
                            ^-----^--- bad quotes
```

Field and table names cannot be quoted with `'` single quotes. If they're NOT a reserved word, then no quotes are necessary. If you insist on using quotes, then use backticks:

```
 $nuovidati = "CREATE TABLE `$user`
                            ^-----^--- proper quotes for field/table names
```

Comment: I need to rename table with username on registration

Answer (score 0):

`auto_increment` column  must be defined as a key:

try this

```
  id mediumint(9) NOT NULL Primary key AUTO_INCREMENT
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^--//-must define key here.
```

and also

```
  CREATE TABLE '$user'
```

must be

```
  CREATE TABLE `$user`
```

or

```
  CREATE TABLE $user
```

[working demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e540)

Comment: How not working? what error? you see well the working demo.

Comment: then tell us what the error message you get. Either the query succeeds, or it fails and by your code will spit out the exact mysql error message.